# I'm using python threading and when querying mysql the code seems to run and stays in an endless loop, returning no errors

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading

I'm calling two functions at the same time and the functions are triggered, but when the mysql query is made, the code seems to run and stays in an infinite loop, not returning an error.

here is my code:

**main.py**

```
import threading
import siparis_kontrolu
import dolar_euro_guncelle

def dd1():
    print("a")
    siparis_kontrolu.siparis_kontrolu()


def dd2():
    print("b")
    dolar_euro_guncelle.dolar_euro_guncelle()

t1 = threading.Thread(target=dd1)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=dd2)

t1.start()
t2.start()
```

**siparis_kontrolu.py**

```
import mysql_db
def siparis_kontrolu():
    try:
        while True:
            print("test1")
            tum_kullanicilar = mysql_db.mysql_get_all("select * from users")
            print("test2")
```

**dolar_euro_guncelle.py**

```
import urllib.request
import json
import mysql_db
import time
import logla


def dolar_euro_guncelle():
    while True:
        try:
            print("f")
            data = urllib.request.urlopen(
                "https://finans.truncgil.com/today.json")
            for line in data:
                line = json.loads(line.decode('utf-8'))
                USD = round(float(line['USD']["Satış"].replace(",", ".")), 2)
                EUR = round(float(line['EUR']["Satış"].replace(",", ".")), 2)
                mysql_db.mysql_update("update variables set EUR='" +
                                      str(EUR)+"', USD='"+str(USD)+"' where id='4'")
            time.sleep(10)
            print("USD/EUR guncellendi.")
        except Exception as e:
            logla.logla(e, "dolar_euro_guncelle")
            print(e)
```

**mysql_db.py**

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
import mysql.connector

config_file = 'config.ini'
config = ConfigParser()
config.read(config_file)

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host=config['MYSQL']['DB_HOST'],
                               user=config['MYSQL']['DB_USERNAME'], passwd=config['MYSQL']['DB_PASSWORD'], database=config['MYSQL']['DB_DATABASE'])
mycursor = mydb.cursor(buffered=True, dictionary=True)

def mysql_update(sorgu):
    try:
        mycursor.execute(sorgu)
        mydb.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

def mysql_get_all(sorgu):
    try:
        mycursor.execute(sorgu)
        return mycursor.fetchall()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

When I run main.py these are written to the console:

a

b

f

test1

test2 and USD/EUR guncellendi is not printed, I don't understand exactly what's wrong, when I trigger siparis_kontrolu.py directly without using threading, it works fine

It remains as it appears in the picture and the code does not stop.
But it doesn't do what I want it to do.

[image]

Comment: Does the problem still happen if you don't call `dolar_euro_guncelle.dolar_euro_guncelle()`? Does it still happen if you don't create or start the `t2 = threading.Thread(target=dd2)` thread? If the problem depends on that code, then we'll need to see some version of it that causes the problem, in order to explain what is going on. Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and [mre]. Make sure that someone else can **copy and paste** the code in the question, **without adding or changing anything**, and see the problem directly.

Comment: "the code seems to run and stays in an infinite loop" This description of the problem doesn't seem to make sense. The loop shown in this code has calls to `print` in it, but you are not seeing those `print` calls repeated continuously. Did you mean that the call to `mysql_get_all` seems to freeze (hang)?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Sorry for my bad english, my native language is not english. @KarlKnechtel

Comment: I'll edit the question to make it a little more clear (for anyone to copy and paste) @KarlKnechtel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a concurrency issue with the DB connection (assuming your `siparis_kontrolu.py` doesn't throw syntax errors due to the missing `except` / `finally` part of the `try` statement, a `sleep` is also missing).

The "SELECT" statements conflict with the "Update" statements.

So it turns out: each thread needs its own database connection!

The easiest way is to open another database connection and create another cursor (maybe another cursor instance is enough) in your `mysql_db.py`:

```py
from configparser import ConfigParser
import mysql.connector

config_file = 'config.ini'
config = ConfigParser()
config.read(config_file)

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host=config['MYSQL']['DB_HOST'],
                               user=config['MYSQL']['DB_USERNAME'], passwd=config['MYSQL']['DB_PASSWORD'], database=config['MYSQL']['DB_DATABASE'])
mycursor = mydb.cursor(buffered=True, dictionary=True)

mydb_upd = mysql.connector.connect(host=config['MYSQL']['DB_HOST'],
                               user=config['MYSQL']['DB_USERNAME'], passwd=config['MYSQL']['DB_PASSWORD'], database=config['MYSQL']['DB_DATABASE'])
mycursor_upd = mydb_upd.cursor(buffered=True, dictionary=True)

def mysql_update(sorgu):
    try:
        mycursor_upd.execute(sorgu)
        mydb_upd.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

def mysql_get_all(sorgu):
    try:
        mycursor.execute(sorgu)
        return mycursor.fetchall()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

But creating a `DbHandler` class and use instances of it in the several threads would be much cleaner.

Comment: What you're describing makes a lot of sense, and that's most likely the source of the problem. I will test and evaluate this as soon as possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tested, this is the source of the problem.